# Polynomials invariant up to sign

Tags: polynomials, invariant-theory

Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be an unknown homogeneous degree-$d$ polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Suppose that a permutation group $G$ acts on $(\mathbb{Q}^n)^*$ so that $f({\bf x}) = 0$ if and only if $f(g \cdot {\bf x}) = 0$ for all $g \in G$. [In my particular case, $n=9$, $d=8$, and $G =$ the symmetry group on the edges of a triangular prism $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times S_3$]

I would like to use the tools of invariant theory to find generators of a minimal submodule of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_d$ guaranteed to contain $f({\bf x})$. However, the polynomials may not be quite invariant; if $g \in G$ has even order, then $f(g \cdot {\bf x})$ might be $-f({\bf x})$.

Is there literature addressing this variation on invariant theory (or a simple trick I'm missing)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: An $f$ such that $f(g\cdot x) = \chi(g)f(x)$, where $\chi:G\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ is a group homomorphism, is called a *semi-invariant* of $G$ with *weight* $\chi$. https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Semi-invariant(2) These are a traditional topic in invariant theory.

Comment: (More generally, $\chi$ can map $G$ to roots of unity, but in $\mathbb{Q}$, $\{\pm 1\}$ are the only roots of unity.)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? Since $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]_d$ isn't stable under multiplication by anything not in $\mathbb{Q}$, by "minimal submodule" do you mean minimal $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace? In which case, $\langle f\rangle_\mathbb{Q}$ is evidently the minimal submodule, so I'm not sure what you're actually looking for?

Comment: Sorry stepped away from this for too long. I was looking for the minimal Q-subspace. I didn't actually know what the polynomial was so I wanted to make sure I was searching in a Q-subspace where I might find it. In the end, what I believe I was looking for were the collection of subspaces generated by 1-d irreps with the same character.

Comment: I.e., the semi-invariants of the 1-d irreps?